# Ember clone model for new record

Tags: ember.js

I want to make a clone of a model currently being edited.

I've found a couple of ways that almost work. But neither are perfect.

1) `model.get('data.attributes')` gets all the attributes except for relationships in camelCase form, generates a new record fine but the relationships are missing of course.

2) `model.serialize()` generates a JSON object, with all attributes including relationships. But `createRecord` will not handle it well since the object is not camelCased (attributes with underscores like `first_name` will not be handled)

After my clone has been created I want to `transaction.createRecord(App.Document, myNewModelObject)` change/set a couple of attributes and finally `commit()`. Anyone have some insight in how to do this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here's an updated answer, it still doesn't handle `hasMany` relationships.

```
cloneBelongsTo: function(fromModel, toModel) {
  var relationships;
  relationships = Em.get(fromModel.constructor, 'relationships');
  return relationships.forEach(function(relationshipType) {
    var _relType;
    _relType = relationships.get(relationshipType);
    return _relType.forEach(function(relationship) {
      var name, relModel;
      relModel = Em.get(fromModel, relationship.name);
      if (relationship.kind === 'belongsTo' && relModel !== null) {
        name = relationship.name;
        return toModel.set(name, fromModel.get(name));
      }
    });
  });
}
```

And here's how I use it:

```
// create a JSON representation of the old model
var newModel = oldModel.toJSON();
// set the properties you want to alter
newModel.public = false;
// create a new record
newDocument = store.createRecord('document', newModel);
// call the cloneBelongsTo method after the record is created
cloneBelongsTo(model, newDocument);
// finally save the new model
newDocument.save();
```

Comment: I have now an example of adding belongsTo items also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20477301/1153884

Comment: Did you figure out how to do hasMany? I ended up doing this which seems to work, but it probably isn't the best way.
`this.eachRelationship(function(key, relationship){
self._data[key].forEach(function(obj) {
newRecord.get(key).addObject(obj);
})
});`

Answer (score 5):

Now we have a add-on to copy models 
[ember-cli-copyable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-copyable)

With this add on, just add the `Copyable` mix-in to the target model which is to be copied and use the copy method

Example from the add-on site

```
import Copyable from 'ember-cli-copyable';

Account = DS.Model.extend( Copyable, {
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  playlists: DS.hasMany('playList'),
  favoriteSong: DS.belongsTo('song')
});

PlayList = DS.Model.extend( Copyable, {
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  songs: DS.hasMany('song'),
});

//notice how Song does not extend Copyable 
Song = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  artist: DS.belongsTo('artist'),
});
//now the model can be copied as below
this.get('currentAccount.id') // => 1 
this.get('currentAccount.name') // => 'lazybensch' 
this.get('currentAccount.playlists.length') // => 5 
this.get('currentAccount.playlists.firstObject.id') // => 1 
this.get('currentAccount.favoriteSong.id') // => 1 

this.get('currentAccount').copy().then(function(copy) {

  copy.get('id') // => 2 (differs from currentAccount) 
  copy.get('name') // => 'lazybensch' 
  copy.get('playlists.length') // => 5 
  copy.get('playlists.firstObject.id') // => 6 (differs from currentAccount) 
  copy.get('favoriteSong.id') // => 1 (the same object as in currentAccount.favoriteSong) 

});
```

Answer (score 3):

How about using toJSON() method instead of serialize()  like this

`js
transaction.createRecord(App.Document, model.toJSON());`

Comment: toJSON() cannot be used if there are relationships, which is a quite common requirement.

Answer (score 1):

Most simple way I found:

```
function cloneModel(model) {
  const root = model._internalModel.modelName;
  const store = model.get('store');
  let attrs = model.toJSON();

  attrs.id = `clone-${attrs.id}`;
  store.pushPayload({
    [root]: attrs
  });
  return store.peekRecord(root, attrs.id);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/offirgolan/ember-data-copyable. Been using this package for some time now, and it is very much reliable. Some of its features :

- Shallow & deep copy an Ember Data model
- Shallow & deep copy model relationships
- Handles cyclical relationships
- Handles custom transforms to create true copies
- Overwrite, ignore attributes, and copy objects by reference
- Intelligent failure and cleanup
- Uses ember-concurrency to allow cancelling a copy task

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simple way to clone your **Ember Model with relationships. working fine.**

Create a Copyable mixin like,

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Mixin.create(Ember.Copyable, {

    copy(deepClone) {
      var model = this, attrs = model.toJSON(), class_type = model.constructor;
      var root = Ember.String.decamelize(class_type.toString().split(':')[1]);

      if(deepClone) {
          this.eachRelationship(function(key, relationship){
              if (relationship.kind == 'belongsTo') {
                  attrs[key] = model.get(key).copy(true);
              } else if(relationship.kind == 'hasMany' && Ember.isArray(attrs[key])) {
                  attrs[key].splice(0);
                  model.get(key).forEach(function(obj) {
                      attrs[key].addObject(obj.copy(true));
                  });
              }
          });
      }
      return this.store.createRecord(root, attrs);
    }
});
```

Add the mixin in your model,

**Note: If you want to clone your child model then, you need to include the mixin in child model as well**

USAGE:

1. With relationship : YOURMODEL.copy(true)
2. Without relationship : YOURMODEL.copy()

Answer (score 0):

This will also solve my problem

```
Account = DS.Model.extend({
   name: DS.attr('string'),
   playlists: DS.hasMany('playList'),
   favoriteSong: DS.belongsTo('song')
});

Duplicate = Ember.Object.extend({});

TemporaryRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
   model : function(){
      var model = this.store.findAll('account');
      var json = model.toJSON(); 
      var duplicateModel = Duplicate.create(json);
      this.set('duplicateModel', duplicateModel);
      return model;
   }
});
```

Comment: `findAll` returns Promise. so you can't do `model.toJSON` immediately.