# Ember.js Clone an existing record into the store

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I am struggling with the concept Ember.js will like. What I want is the following. I have now an existing Ember Data model called `Article`. Lets say with the `id` of 1 will be shown on `/article/1`.

When the user hit the New button they are transitioned to the 'article.new' route. See my routers:

```
App.Router.map(function () {
   this.resource('article', {path: '/article/:id'});
   this.resource('article.new', {path: "/article/new"});
}
```

When the user click the **Duplicate** button when they are at `/article/1` the `duplicateArticle` action gets called. I intuitively do the following in `App.ArticleController`:

```
duplicateArticle: function () {
   return this.transitionToRoute('article.new', this.get('model');
}
```

However that is not going to work. I think because I need an path in my article.new route. However, when a user click on the New button I do not need an ID.

Is there a valid solution to this question?

**Edit: My tries so far:**

```
var currentArticle = this.get('model'); 
currentArticle.set('id', null); 
var duplicatedArticle = this.store.createRecord('article', currentArticle); 
duplicatedArticle.save();
```

and:

```
var duplicatedArticle = Ember.copy(this.get('model'), true);
```

and:

```
 var newArticle = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.get('model')));
 var duplicatedArticle = this.store.createRecord('article', newArticle);
 duplicatedArticle.save();
```

The last try does work except for `belongsTo` and `hasMany` properties.

Is there no Ember way of doing this?

**References:**

[Ember clone model for new record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14912425/ember-clone-model-for-new-record)

[Is there any way to convert Ember Object into plain javascript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15001409/is-there-any-way-to-convert-ember-object-into-plain-javascript-object)

[Iterating over Ember.js ember-data Record Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138383/iterating-over-ember-js-ember-data-record-arrays)

[How can I clone an Ember Data record, including relationships?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20007049/how-can-i-clone-an-ember-data-record-including-relationships) (not answered, 75% the same question as me)

.

## Update: a simple example with also **belongsTo** items saved

*hasMany does not work. Contribute to this answer if you have a solution!*

My final solution without hasMany items is now as follows:

In my actions of my ArticleController:

```
  duplicateArticle: function () {
        var article = this.get('model').toJSON(),
            self = this;

        // todo implement saving hasMany items

        // set belongsTo items by hand
        article['landcode'] = this.get('landcode');
        article['employee'] = this.get('employee');
        article['cross_selling_article_relation'] = this.get('cross_selling_article_relation');

        var duplicatedArticle = this.store.createRecord('article', article);

        // save and transite to newly created article
        duplicatedArticle.save().then(function (savedArticle) {
            self.transitionToRoute('article', savedArticle.id);
        });
    },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ember Data is in beta, so missing functionality is to be expected, relationships are only resolved from ids when resolved through find.

If you create a dummy id you can pushPayload then find.

W/o relationships, you can use record.toJSON() to get the attributes w/o id, then send it to createRecord.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OxIDiVU/13/edit

You should submit a PR with duplicate logic, it would be a great way to contribute to the community.

Comment: I rewarded you for your example. However I add my solution to my question above. Thanks!

Comment: @kingpin2k I've had this issue a couple of times, too... what would the PR have in it? A failing use case? I don't quite follow that.

Comment: attempting to duplicate a record?  Or assigning the relationships?  Submitting a PR with a failing test case is good, where the functionality already exists, but has an issue, but for new functionality submitting a PR with the new functionality goes a lot farther.

Comment: Is there a way to get the model name used, without hard-coding it in, within the ``createRecord()`` method?  I am using a generic ``itemController``, and would like to do this.  I have access to the model via ``this.get("model")``, so I assume there's something like ``this.get("model").get("modelName")``?

Answer (score 4):

Now we have a add-on to copy models [ember-cli-copyable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-copyable)

With this add on, just add the Copyable mix-in to the target model which is to be copied and use the copy method

Example from the add-on site

```
import Copyable from 'ember-cli-copyable';

Account = DS.Model.extend( Copyable, {
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  playlists: DS.hasMany('playList'),
  favoriteSong: DS.belongsTo('song')
});

PlayList = DS.Model.extend( Copyable, {
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  songs: DS.hasMany('song'),
});

//notice how Song does not extend Copyable 
Song = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  artist: DS.belongsTo('artist'),
});
//now the model can be copied as below
this.get('currentAccount.id') // => 1 
this.get('currentAccount.name') // => 'lazybensch' 
this.get('currentAccount.playlists.length') // => 5 
this.get('currentAccount.playlists.firstObject.id') // => 1 
this.get('currentAccount.favoriteSong.id') // => 1 

this.get('currentAccount').copy().then(function(copy) {

  copy.get('id') // => 2 (differs from currentAccount) 
  copy.get('name') // => 'lazybensch' 
  copy.get('playlists.length') // => 5 
  copy.get('playlists.firstObject.id') // => 6 (differs from currentAccount) 
  copy.get('favoriteSong.id') // => 1 (the same object as in currentAccount.favoriteSong) 

});
```

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution for copying/duplicating an Ember Data record, including its one-to-many relationships.

I have a "duplicate" method:

```
duplicate: function(oldObject) {
  var newObject = oldObject.toJSON();
  for (var key in newObject) {
    if (newObject[key] != oldObject.get(key)) {
        newObject[key] = oldObject.get(key);
    }
  }
  newObject.id = null;
  return newObject;
}
```

And I use this method in an action like this:

```
actions: {
  draft: function() {
    var newModel = this.duplicate(this.get('model'));
    this.store.createRecord('somemodel', newModel).save();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What if you nested the "new" route under your edit so you wouldn't need any extra params in the url. Then to "duplicate" it you could reach up to the parent route using this.modelFor('article')

Comment: Thanks for your help, however then I get an error stating that the ID already exists. I have also tried `var newArticle = Ember.copy(this.get('model', true))`. But that does also not work. I cannot accept that there is not an easy 'Emberlike' solution for this.:-) I try further, if you have any thoughts, I like to hear them!

Comment: Also I do not understand why this does not work: `var currentArticle = this.get('model');
            currentArticle.set('id', null);
            var duplicatedArticle = this.store.createRecord('article', currentArticle);
            duplicatedArticle.save();`

Comment: That doesn't work because an ember Model object isn't a JS Object...  so you can't create one from an existing one... createRecord expects a JS object passed in.